# detect the need of ActiveRecord eager load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

Is there any tool/automation which will identify the need of ActiveRecord eager load and warn the same.

Can any fix to ActiveRecord fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try bullet gem. After installing and configuring the gem, it will notify you of places in your app, where eager loading could be appropriate.

More info: https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet